# Enter key and tab not working for focus class

Tags: html, css, focus, accessibility

I am trying to tab the buttons for accessibility reasons in the header however I am not able to tab over them.

I have the following css

```css
.nmcnav_clickable:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
  }

.nmcnav_clickable {
    .noButton;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: var(--primary-height);
    cursor: pointer;
    // don't show an outline when not tabbing
    &:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
        outline: none;
    }
    &:focus {
        outline: currentColor solid;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    &:hover {
        .nmcnav_text {
            color: @color-teal;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my HTML

```
    {% macro navbutton(item) %}
        <button tabindex="0"
            class="nmcnav_clickable nmcnav_button"
            aria-controls="nmcnav_dropdown-{{ item.id }}"
            aria-expanded="false"
            id="nmcnav_button-{{ item.id }}">
            <span class="nmcnav_text">{{ item.title|raw }}</span>
        </button>
    {% endmacro %}

    {% macro navlink(item) %}
    <a 
        class="nmcnav_clickable {{ item.meta('button') ? 'nmcnav_btn' : '' }}"
        href="{{ item.get_link }}"{% if item.target %} target="{{ item.target }}"{% endif %}>
        <span class="nmcnav_text {{ item.meta('button') ? 'btn' : '' }}">{{ item.title|raw }}</span>
    </a>
    {% endmacro %}
```

There was a point where I was able to <kbd>tab</kbd> over the buttons but then I realized I was not able to press <kbd>enter</kbd> to actually access the links because tabindex only works with `<a>` or `<button>` tags. But when I try and change the tabindex to the buttons, nothing happens. I need to be able to tab over and enter for the buttons. I have also attached a ss of what the header should look like. [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code that's generated, without all the {% stuff?  That is, bring up the code inspector for your page and copy/paste the code from there.  A real `<button>` is focusable with TAB and accepts the ENTER key. You don't need `tabindex`. A link is also focusable and accepts the ENTER key **if** it has an `href` attribute, which I think your example does but it's hard to say if it actually generates a value for href.

Comment: Might the `.noButton` mixin interfere with anything? Sounds sketchy to apply this on a class that actually *is* used in a button. But there is no CSS property that could interfere with keyboard events, or is there?

Comment: @Sarah, does your focus skip the buttons and continue after the header?
Also, could you provide the JavaScript code that binds on the button’s events? Thanks.